# Can I find and replace RegEx in VScode to replace the found RegEx without quotations?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Quick question:

I wanted to use RegEx to find and replace instances where columns in a csv have " " in them, as it would cause it to create a new column.

for example,

> "Name", "DOB", "Description", "Status"

> "Samuel Smith","01-01-1969","Likes to go by "Sam", "Open"

This translates to

| Name | DOB | Description | Status |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Samuel Smith | 01-01-1969 | Likes to go by | Sam | Open |

I know I can use [ "(.*?)" ] to find these instances, but is there a way I can replace it so it just returns Sam instead of "Sam"?

Does my question make sense? thanks

Comment: Just capture the text between double quotes and use $1 to refer captured group in replace

Answer (score 1):

Replace with `$1` in this case to take the contents of the first capturing group `(...)`.

`$0` is the entire match, each higher number after that represents the next capturing group.

Comment: It won't work in the general case as there can be `,` commas inside quoted field values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Find :   "(.*?)"
Replace: $1
```

Input:

```
"Name", "DOB", "Description", "Status"

"Samuel Smith","01-01-1969","Likes to go by" "Sam", "Open"
```

Output:

```
Name, DOB, Description, Status

Samuel Smith,01-01-1969,Likes to go by Sam, Open
```

Comment: It won't work in the general case as there can be `,` commas inside quoted field values.

Comment: Not sure If I understand correctly. But I just tested with an example "Sam,Sam" and above removes quotes and outputs as Sam,Sam. Is this what you mean ?